# CommunityEngine Rails3 Git-Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debian, communityengine

I'm a newbie in Rails3 but i will be only install CommunityEngine. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/tree/rails3), but I could not get it to work.

This is the error:

> root@develoepr:/home/pthoelken/cengine# bundle install --binstubs
>
> Fetching bborn/communityengine fatal: repository 'bborn/communityengine' does not exist Git error: command `git clone bborn/communityengine
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/cache/bundler/git/communityengine-551de75f7b47f61c52169b8870957a774ec7f423"--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /home/pthoelken/cengine has failed.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the answer [this link](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/issues/37)

> Update your Gemfile
>   gem 'community_engine' , :git => 'https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git', :branch => 'rails3'